# Very strange result while writing a trace of matrix

Tags: matrices

My Jacobian matrix evaluated at the equilibrium is denoted by `J_E`. I typed for its trace as

`tr\textit{J_E}`.

And the result is very strange. `tr` appears good but `\textit{J_E}` part is unlimitedly repeated with its size gradually decreasing.

It looks something like:

[image: Like this]

where the `J_E` part is gradually getting smaller.

What is happening here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Not sure what is going on as you did not post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) the reproduces the problem. But you should be using `\usepackage{amsmath}\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{tr}` in the preamble and then  `$\trace J_E $`.  The underscore to indicate subscript has to be in math mode.

Comment: Could you add a picture, showing this strange result? Now you have enough reputation to do it...

Comment: @Peter Grill thanks so much. My problem is resolved!

Comment: I think your editor is compiling in nonstop mode and it keeps trying to add the missing `$` sign since inside `\textit` an underscore should be in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should you type `\textit{J_E}`? This is wrong for several reasons.

1. `_` requires math mode and the argument to `\textit` is typeset in text mode (as the command name suggests).
2. `\textit` is the wrong command for typesetting a math variable: math mode should be used.
3. You're right that “tr” for the trace should be in upright type, but typesetting a formula not in math mode just for this is misusing the tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}
$\tr J_{E}$ is the trace of $J_{E}$.
\end{document}
```

Now, why the four repetitions? You first of all get an error message that says

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8 \textit{J_E}
```

(the line number can be different, of course). After this the output is unpredictable, because when TeX discovers the error it's too late for doing a sensible fix.